# How to check NICS Configuration for vcenter using PS

Tags: powershell, vmware, powershell-4.0, powercli, vcenter

I need to get details for "Quality of Service", Adopter policies and MTU using powershell for a particular VMHost

I have written the following command but it is not giving all details.

`Get-VirtualSwitch -VMHost abc.com | ft Name,Mtu,Nic`

```
Output:
Name                        Mtu Nic
----                        --- ---
Name1                       9000
```

Comment: I am missing `QoS` and  `Adopter policies` information

Comment: QoS is a function of a distributed switch, are you using distributed switches? If so, the property for whether or not QoS is supported is at: (Get-vdswitch -Name vdswitchname).ExtensionData.Capability.FeaturesSupported.NetworkResourceManagementCapability.QosSupported

Answer (score 1):

You are telling it to format a table with only those 3 properties. Try:

```
Get-VirtualSwitch -VMHost abc.com | fl
```

Comment: It is giving other properties but not giving `QoS` and `Adopter policies` information. Can you help me identify the correct cmdlet?